# result comes with adding different different columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

this is the given tables data ,i want the output like this as given by me .

```
slno    name        salary
-----------------------------
1       raj         5000.0000
2       laba        4000.0000
3       silu        3000.0000
4       jaya        6000.0000
5       papu        7000.0000
6       tikan       9000.0000
7       susanta     6000.0000
8       chiku       4500.0000
9       micky       5500.0000
10      susa        2500.0000
11      musa        6500.0000
12      pi          6500.0000
13      luna        7500.0000
14      tuna        9500.0000
15      tina        3500.0000
```

Desired output

```
slno    name    salary
----------------------
1       raj     5000.0000
2       laba    4000.0000
3       silu    3000.0000
4       jaya    6000.0000
5       papu    7000.0000
6-10    ----    27500.0000(total salary from 6-10)
6-15    ----    61000.0000(total salary from 6-15)
```

Comment: The question is missing the part, what you have worked for it. Please provide the query, which you tried.

Comment: i want the first 5 row comes like as usual in the table value ,after that in 6 row the slno shows 6-10 no name totalsalary(6-10) and 7th row slno shows 6-10 no mane totalsalary(6-15)

Comment: my query-select * from emp_salary2 where slno<=5
select SUM(salary)as salary from emp_salary2 where slno between 5 and 10 union 
select SUM(salary)as salary from emp_salary2 where slno between 5 and 15 

select distinct case  
    --when slno between 0 and 5 then ' 0- 5' 
    when slno between 5 and 10 then '5-10'
    else '5-15'end as slno
  from emp_salary2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #table_name (slno int, name varchar(20), salary float);
insert into #table_name (slno, name, salary) values
(1, 'raj', 5000.0000),
(2, 'laba', 4000.0000),
(3, 'silu', 3000.0000),
(4, 'jaya', 6000.0000),
(5, 'papu', 7000.0000),
(6, 'tikan', 9000.0000),
(7, 'susanta', 6000.0000),
(8, 'chiku', 4500.0000),
(9, 'micky', 5500.0000),
(10, 'susa', 2500.0000),
(11, 'musa', 6500.0000),
(12, 'pi', 6500.0000),
(13, 'luna', 7500.0000),
(14, 'tuna', 9500.0000),
(15, 'tina', 3500.0000);

select cast(slno as varchar(10)) [slno]
, name
, salary 
from #table_name where slno <= 5
union all
select '6-10'
, '----'
, sum(salary) 
from #table_name where slno between 6 and 10
union all
select '6-15'
, '----'
, sum(salary) 
from #table_name where slno between 6 and 15
```

Result

```
slno    name    salary
----------------------
1       raj     5000
2       laba    4000
3       silu    3000
4       jaya    6000
5       papu    7000
6-10    ----    27500
6-15    ----    61000
```

Comment: its static way,i am not want static

Comment: if you want dynamic solution - please explain the rules of splitting the dataset. and why you need dynamic? there may be `slno` higher then 15?

Comment: Through normalization i am splitting the tables in database that's why i need to be it dynamic

Comment: but what is the rule? for example "I want to split all the tables it the way that first 5 rows remains unchanged and all subsequent rows must be grouped together by 5 and in this case their number should be changed to string in format [first_id-last_id], name should be changed to '------' and salary should be summarized" - that is what you want?